# How write in line if condition in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to write inline if condition in xslt. I have mentioned my tried code below. I am getting an error mark when I am using it. Please note me where I am incorrect

```
<xsl:template match="node">
  <entry type="{if (ancestor::table[@frame='all']) then 'all_rules' else 'header_single{if ($out) then concat('_',$out) else ''}'}">
     <body/>
  </entry>
</xsl:template>
```

Error :

```
{...hen concat('_',$out) else '...}: Unexpected token name "_" beyond end of expression
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `{ ... }` to contain expressions is an XSLT feature, not XPath, so you can't use it within an XPath expression.

If you want to nest `if`-expressions like this, then you need to do so within the constructs of XPath, and I believe that means using `concat()` in this case:

```
if (ancestor::table[@frame='all']) 
then 'all_rules' 
else concat(
    'header_single',
    if ($out) then concat('_',$out) else ''
)
```

Of course, you need to be using a high enough version of XSLT in order for this to work. This won't work in XSLT 1.0 as that only supports XPath 1.0, which doesn't have `if-` expressions.